# 2 NICs, same IP, only one connected at a time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

My Linux, Ubuntu 18.04 machine has 2 NICs, One is in use, the other is disconnected.

I want to switch from one to the other, with absolutely minimal downtime.

Can I assign identical IPs to both then just pull out the cable from one and stick it in the other?

Answer (score 2):

You can just assign both interfaces to bridge and assign IP address to bridge, then you will be able to just plug in / out any time.

At /etc/network/interfaces

```
 iface br0 inet static
   address 192.168.1.10
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 192.168.1.1
   dns-nameservers 192.168.1.5
   dns-search example.com
   bridge_ports eth0 eth1
   bridge_stp off
   bridge_fd 0
   bridge_maxwait 0
```

Comment: ok, probably works too. thx

Answer (score 0):

I did it... got bored of waiting for you guys.

Just assign same to both.

Works

```
sudo vi /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
[make changes]
sudo netplan apply
[switch cables]
```